# GSDMM topic by each row of text

Tags: python, text-mining

have been trying to figure out how to get the topic assigned to each row of text in GSDMM.

Attempted to follow ([A practical example of GSDMM in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108771/a-practical-example-of-gsdmm-in-python)) example by Pie-ton but get an error

AttributeError: 'MovieGroupProcess' object has no attribute 'fit'.

Is there a different package to install other than https://pypi.org/project/GPyM-TM/ to have the 'fit' option work?

Have also tried https://github.com/rwalk/gsdmm

but after running 'from gsdmm import MovieGroupProcess'
get an error of 'No module named 'gsdmm'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first checkout the code from the github repo.
Steps are given below:

```
% mkdir gsdmm
% cd gsdmm 
% git clone https://github.com/rwalk/gsdmm .
% python
>>> from gsdmm import MovieGroupProcess
```